# Visual Studio 2010 Slow to Load

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper

I have been happily using VS 2010 for several weeks without any performance problems.

I installed dotCover from JetBrains several days ago and things continued to run well, but ran my first code coverage test earlier today. I double clicked on one of the report results and it successfully took me to the referenced line of code.

I inadvertantly right clicked on the line of code, brining up the context menu and the navigate menu item was hightlighted.

Moments later, Visual Studio froze and subsequently crashed.

I closed and reopened and Visual Studio wouldn't open cleanly. I uninstalled dotCover and was able to get Visual Studio to open, but it took several minutes just to get to the project open screen.

I also am showing that devenv.exe quickly runs up to 1,500,000 K and doesn't ever recover. I'm not sure what it was running at when I wasn't having problems, but I can't believe it was this high.

I am now doubtful that the problem was with dotCover, but maybe some intellisense cache or something. Who knows?

I do seem to get some relief when I set an Above Normal priority on the devenv.exe process, but the machine doesn't appear to be cpu bound.

Has anyone seen similar problems or have any suggestions?

Comment: I would try and re-initialize the Visual Studio installation.  You can do this via the VS Command prompt by running `devenv /setup`

Comment: I had already tried devenv /setup - sorry for not clarifying that in the initial post. Thanks for the response anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmya, the add-in market for Visual Studio is a whole new ball game in the DLL Hell stadium.  VS2010 consuming 1 1/2 *gigabytes* of memory is completely absurd of course.  Plain vanilla it is an incredibly low ~300 MB or so.

Download SysInternals' ProcMon utility and find out what file that blasted add-in is reading to get it out of control this badly.  The tool will generates a lot of trace data, you should however have no trouble finding out what file is responsible given how long it takes.  Delete it.  You probably ought to consider uninstalling it next, this is just sloppy.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer, but it turns out it absolutely was ReSharper causing the problem. Uninstalled and everything fires up immediately. I will attempt a reinstall of ReSharper tomorrow, hopefully with better results. Thanks, Hal

Comment: devenv.exe with large project loaded and debugging is running at 158,488 K.

Comment: Just reinstalled ReSharper - exact same problem. devenv.exe @ 1,161,000 K and growing. I'm going to uninstall and open a ticket with JetBrains.

Comment: Interesting to note. Several plugins that I installed are still there and active in ReSharper. I'm attempting to remove the plugins, but the dialog box is freezing when I click OK after deselecting. I suspect that the problem could still be in one of those plugins.

Comment: *** After removing all plugins manually - deleting the files from the c:\users\myusername\AppData\[Roaming|Local]\jetbrains\[version]\plugins directories, everything loads fast and flawless... Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Did you delete all ReSharper plug-ins in one go, or one by one? (Interesting to know which one had the critical impact on memory usage.) If you did delete them in one go, can you please provide us with the list of the plug-ins that you had installed so we can reproduce the problem internally? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the feedback information. please accept out apologies for the bad experience you have had with our tools. 
Please try installing latest release build of R# 5.1.1 from http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/index.html 
Please let me know if this helps. We have fixed some critical performance issues in the latest release.
Also, please try to notice if performance lag will start after dotCover installation. I have also posted this on StackOverFlow.

Comment: Thank Kirill. I have always been pleased with Resharper and continue to be. I was able to confirm that the problem was neither resharper nor dotCover, but with one of the third party Resharper plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all plugins manually, see comments on accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

For googlers, I have found that the **VMDebugger Add-In** by VMWare when Workstation is installed alone causes very slow load times for VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by disabling all addins and then re-enabling them again until I found the one that causes the slowdown.
To speedup VS2010 startup, I found that I had to disable or update the ANTS Profiler addin and disable VMDebugger add-in. Then VS2010 will open then very fast.

To disable the addins, open VS2010 as administrator and from addins manager uncheck both checkboxes (available addins / startup)

You are done!